# Is there any difference between .toNotEqual vs .not.toEqual Jasmine matchers?

Tags: jasmine, protractor, automated-tests

They look totally the same, only toNotEqual matcher does not work on my nodejs/protractor installation.

Comment: The method `toNotEqual` is not present in the Jasmine API: http://jasmine.github.io/edge/introduction.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could have been more useful if you specified the Jasmine Version you are using.

But anyway answer to your question is .. all Jasmine versions 1.3,2.0,2.1 to 2.5 don't support 'toNotEqual' and in case you want to check inequality you have to chain NOT to expect before the matcher

[Jasmine docs](http://jasmine.github.io/)